# Get height of a list element in Android

Tags: android

I need to know the height of a view inside an element in a `ListView` before showing it.

My current code assigns a `OnGlobalLayoutListener` to the `View`, and then I get the height of the element using ´getHeight()´. This code works fine the first time Android renders the element (when it renders the ´ListView´), however, when you scroll up and down, and the app generates the views for the different elements, it doesn't work.

I've been debugging the code, and ´OnGlobalLayout´ is not being fired every time an element is  displayed, but only once when the ´ListView´ is rendered.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you plan to do with that information?

Comment: The list elements are expandables, so I need the height of the expandable area so that I can apply a negative margin to hide it.